# Filtering out wastelands,scrubs,swamps, grasslands etc from LULC for India using ERDAS IMAGINE Model maker?

Tags: erdas-imagine

I have a LULC for India. i need to filter out non-agricultural, non-builtup, non-waterbody, non-forest. simply wastelands,scrubs,swamps, grasslands etc.

Please how to filter these using ERDAS IMAGINE Model maker?